# NodeJS JSON.parse convert the char ! into?

Tags: json, node.js, http, express

i have a problem with JSON.parse() in a NodeJS programm usging Express.
The problem is that when i get an external json using http.get for example like this:

```
[ { "Name" : "Parachutes", "Artist" : "Coldplay"}, { "Name" : "Lost!", "Artist": "Coldplay"  } ]
```

When i do JSON.parse(ResponseStr) the i get the following json

```
[ { "Name" : "Parachutes", "Artist" : "Coldplay"}, { "Name" : "Lost?", "Artist": "Coldplay"  } ]
```

The char ! is converting into ? when i do that JSON.parse, i want to have the same output as the original Name because when i want to use that name in a http.get('/example.com/album/Lost?') it is returning to me a 404 error.

This is mi my code:

```
function httpget(url,callback)
    {
        var str = "";
        http.get(url, function(resp){
            resp.on('data', function(chunk){
                str += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', function(){
                var obj = JSON2.parse(str);
                callback(obj);
            });
        });
    }
```

#### Edit 1:

I already using resp.setEncoding('utf8'); in my code, the problem is in in the JSON2.parse() (is same as JSON.parse()), before that i can do console.log(str) and the output will show "Lost!" but when i do JSON.parse() the output is like this "Lost?"

Comment: Could you share where is the GET URL you get the response from? (the one with `Lost!`). i'm suspecting it is due to the charset. Could you also try to add `resp.setEncoding('utf8');` before the first `resp.on`?

Comment: I tried parsing your string values using the same `JSON.parse` API and it isn't showing '?'. Can you please confirm that the `str` you are parsing at the `resp.on` code block is indeed what it is suppose to be? e.g. put a print statement to see what `str` is like. Also, why do you have `JSON2.parse`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @SamuelToh JSON2 is a json js lib for browsers/environments that don't have `JSON` built-in (old IE.) Why it's being used in a node environment i have no idea.